# MySQL: Auto-increment based on multi-column PK with transaction

Tags: mysql, triggers, auto-increment

I have table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `appKey` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and primary key (`id`,`appKey`)

I would like to have id autoincrement for every appKey independently. So I use trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `messageId` BEFORE INSERT ON `message`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
    declare v_messageId bigint(20) unsigned default 0;
    SELECT max(id) INTO v_messageId FROM message WHERE appKey = new.appKey;
    if (v_messageId IS NULL) THEN
        set v_messageId=0;
    end if;
    SET new.id=v_messageId + 1;
end
```

It works fine until i tried to insert two rows from two database connection (I am using connection pool in application) at same time. First row is inserted. But second throws error ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '18-secretkey' for key 'PRIMARY'.

I know why this is happening. My question is: Is MySQL possible to achieves this task or I have to use different database (probably PostgreSQL because of advisory lock)?

**EDIT:**

In table I have this rows:

```
id | appKey | text
---+--------+-----------
 1 | key 1  | something
 2 | key 1  | something
 1 | key 2  | something
 2 | key 2  | something
 3 | key 1  | something
```

And the error is after I try to insert this two rows:

```
appKey | text
-------+-------
 key1  | something
 key1  | something
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html use the built in tools.  The exception handling for race conditions using max(ID) plus one is quite the headache

Comment: @xBert I guess you dont understand my problem. I edited question.

Comment: From above link, "MyISAM Notes
For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups."  I really don't understand your question if this isn't what you're trying to do.

Comment: @xQbert I am using InnoDB engine and can't use MyISAM. This is why I am trying to solve this with trigger.

Comment: Not sure why I missed that syntax... sorr.y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd strongly suggest you don't manage ids on your own. There is no business value in doing so.

Now in case you want to stick with it, for some reason, at least make use of `LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`. It's **the only** multi-user safe way to generate sequences in MySQL. Also you would need additional table to store sequences per appKey.

```sql
CREATE TABLE message_seq (
  appKey VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  seq BIGINT(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Your trigger then will look like

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `messageId` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `message`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO message_seq(appkey, seq) VALUES (NEW.appKey, LAST_INSERT_ID(1)) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE seq = LAST_INSERT_ID(seq + 1);    
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5282ed/1)** demo

Further reading:

- [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)